# Jquery ajax url is changed from https to http during running ajax for some reason

Tags: jquery, ajax

My ajax function in wordpress php file:

```
jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'https://example.com/something/dothis.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            method: 'POST',
            data: {...},
            complete: function(data) {
                // doing stuffs
            }
});
```

The url is for some reason converted to http://example.com/something/dothis.php when ajax tries to do the POST request, and obviosuly it's blocked since the site is using https. I can't find anything on Google about this issue.

What on earth could be causing this?

Comment: Did you try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40295307/2181514 another possible: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13556869/2181514.

Comment: Did you trace this in the browser network tab to see if the server is returning a 302?

Comment: @freedomn-m it was actually a redirection issue yes, thanks for solving it!