# AJAX call - 404 Not Found after switch to HTTPS

Tags: .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, https

I know below issue was mentioned many times here but I'm still facing the issue with AJAX call after change protocol from HTTP to HTTPS.

My AJAX call that works on HTTP looks like that:

```
   var dataToSend = {userEmail: "some.email@email.com"} 
   $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     url: "/Service/AplicationService.svc/MethodName",
     data: JSON.stringify(dataToSend),
     dataType: "json",
     success: handleSuccess,
     error:handleError
    })
```

When I use HTTP protocol it works, but after I change to HTTPS protocol it return **404 Not Found**.
I'm using MVC on .NET Framework on backend side.

Can somebody help fix this, please?

EDIT:

I tried add dummy html file into Service path and call this file using https protocol. HTML opened so I think the issue is in service file that block/not allow CROSS Origin calls - how can I turn it on?

Comment: How is the application hosted? It might be a binding missing on IIS.

Comment: @J.Loscos It is hosted on IIS. all bindings are correct, entire app works fine except AJAX call

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery ajax won't make HTTPS requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13556772/jquery-ajax-wont-make-https-requests)

Comment: @EriawanKusumawardhono nope - same issue

Comment: @Sepcio ok... try to set allow CORS on your ASP.NET MVC startup. Then restart your web server and run the app.

Comment: @EriawanKusumawardhono I added allow CORS into my web.config file, but still same issue

Comment: Folks I added additional description, looks like .NET service issue